# Upload image from phone to Amazon S3 then return the image URL

Tags: android, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on an android app and I'm having trouble with one part of it.

I am trying to take a photo, upload this photo to Amazon S3, then get the URL of the image and set it as the image of an ImageView.

Currently I am getting the image from the intent perfectly fine, but I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to upload the image properly using a putObjectRequest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is giving you trouble?  Have you checked out the Getting Started Guide? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html